# Taking pictures using an external (USB) camera on a Samsung Galaxy S2

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, usb-host-mode

Question: How can we take a picture using an external, USB camera, on a Samsung Galaxy S2 (setup in host mode, using an OTG (On The Go) cable), running Android 4.0.3 (Ice Cream Sandwich).

Details:
We are trying to build an app as part of a project, where the phone will be out of sight (e.g. in someone's pocket), but the external camera can take a picture (on demand) that our app can process. We have seen evidence of success using OTG and flash drives/mice/keyboards, but are unsure of what difficulties may arise (and how to approach them) for a USB webcam.

Given that we are trying to write an app (API level 15), other pointers (with regard to interfacing with the external camera) would be appreciated (as a starting point, we really would like to just prove that the camera CAN work - that is, using any existing app, take a picture using the external camera).

Beyond basic recognition and potential problems, we are concerned (perhaps needlessly) about the power that the phone can provide to the USB camera - is it likely that this will be sufficient to power the camera?

If it is not possible to use a USB webcam as an external camera on an Android phone, other suggestions as to how we can setup an external camera to work with the phone, would be appreciated.

**Specifications:**
Android version: 4.0.3 - Ice Cream Sandwich
API level 15
Device: Samsung Galaxy 2 
Model GT-I9100M 
Build Number: IML74K.UGLD3

Answer (score 2):

I found this: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=infinitegra.trial.usbcamera 
This is an Android application to display and record the video from an USB camera which is connected to a smart phone or a tablet device. For more details please check his website: http://www.infinitegra.co.jp/en/solution/AndroidApp1-spec.htm

Answer (score -1):

you should try this: [Webeecam Free-USB Web Camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.econsystems.webeecamtrial)

This android application displays/records video and captures images from a USB UVC camera that is connected to Android phone or tablet device. This a free trial version so you can check if it works.

Comment: Follow [How to not be a spammer](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/promotion). You must disclose your affiliation with the product. Also, it appears that you've been promoting this product on other sites as well, such as : http://androidforums.com/threads/webeecam-free-usb-web-camera-app.957110/ / http://www.droidgamers.com/forums/topic/9581-free-webeecam-free-usb-web-camera-app/