# how to use a remote camera (webcam or Windows-usb) as my Android built-in camera(s)

Tags: usb, camera, remote-control, remote-access

Please read carefully, there are MANY answers to the 'opposite' question from the one I ask here, but I cannot find an answer to the following question:

I have an android device with no built-in camera.  I want to be able to use a REMOTE camera as the "built-in" camera on this android device.  The remote camera could be a (streaming)webcam, or it could be a USB cam attached to a PC.

My requirement is that the android device i use "think" that it has a camera built-in (or even better, two cameras, a front- and rear-facing one), so that I can use Skype, and zoom, and all other camera apps.

I am happy to also need to install software on the remote device where the camera is physically attached.  That remote device is really a windows PC, but if necessary, i could perhaps have it be a Linux box.

Please note that I do NOT need to 'turn' my android camera into a webcam. That is "easy" -- except that I don't have an android camera. That is why i need to do the opposite.  I would be fine to use a very generic solution, for example a "net-usb" client server solution, which would give me a usb-camera on my android. But the solutions i have seen like that are VERY expensive.

Thank you for any help/pointers you can give me.

--scott
PS ("the truth") -- the truth is that I would like to run Skype and Zoom on an android-86 running within a Windows HyperVisor. Unfortuantely, Windows HyperV seems not to support USB, and so i don't know how to add a 'built-in' camera to the android-x86 which I have already running there. Therefore, i can not use SKype or Zoom, since I don't have a camera 'built-in' to this machine.

Comment: Can you clear up this question and be more specific? Because I got lost. In second paragraph you're writing about true Android-based device with no built-in camera. In last (PS) paragraph you are writing about virtual Android device run on Windows HyperVisior. For first (true Android device with USB-attached external camera) -- take a look at [this answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/61609/20449). For other option (virtual Android device), I don't know, if there is any solution.

Comment: Thanks for your question: I assumed (perhaps incorrectly) that a "built-in camera"  on an Android device could be assumed to be attached via USB; I assumed (perhaps incorrectly) that both "built-in" and "external"  cameras are attached  via  USB, and so my question was about android devices where there is no USB, but there is IP. I don't think it should matter if the hardware on which the Android OS is running is "real" or "virtual". In your terms, my question is: "suppose the Android hardware has no camera and no USB, but does have IP. Can I make a remote webcam be the "built-in camera". Thx!

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure about using a 'remote' camera, but as for a USB camera I've found a simple solution for myself as I was having a similar issue. Enable USB 2.0 and go into the Devices tab and Webcams and click on your webcam (assuming it's detected) prior to installing your operating system. This worked great for me with android x86 7.1 RC2

Comment: You just copied @trejder. Please be sure to always read comments as they clarify the OP's question and also will eliminate the possibility of duplicates