# Using external USB camera with Android-based settop box

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, camera, android-tv, smart-tv

I have found many offers for selling settop box-like computers based on Android 4.4. One of them claims to have Skype installed on-board and allows to have Internet calls through TV.

For full video conference, a camera is required and since settop box doesn't have one (it is not a tablet or smartphone), we can only talk about external USV camera, connected through one of USB ports to settop box (notice, that we talk about pure USB port, not microUSB with OTG).

While browsing site, I found [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/61609/20449), that points to an application named *USB Camera Trial* ([Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=infinitegra.trial.usbcamera) and [producer website](http://www.infinitegra.co.jp/en/solution/AndroidApp1-spec.htm)). But, there are only examples for connecting external camera to full featured Android-based smartphone or tablet.

**Will this work with settop box as well? Is Android on board settop box limited in any way or is it as natural as on smartphone or tablet and supports everything as on real mobile device?**